# If $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a lift of the circle homeomorphism $f$, show that $F^n$ is a lift of $f^n$ for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems

By a lift of a circle homeomorphism $f$, I mean that $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies  $\pi\circ F = f\circ \pi $ where $\pi$ is the natural projection $\pi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.  If it helps, I can think of two facts regarding lifts of circle homeomorphisms that may be useful: $F$ is a homeomophism of the real line and $F(x+1)=F(x)\pm 1$.

Let me state the question again in the main text: If $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a lift of the circle homeomorphism $f$, show that $F^n$ is a lift of $f^n$ for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

I can see that an inductive argument holds for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$; since the base case $(n=1)$ is a property of the lift, it follows that:

\begin{equation} \pi\circ F^n = \pi\circ F\circ F^{n-1} = f \circ \pi \circ F^{n-1} = f^{n}\circ \pi.  \end{equation}

However, I am struggling with showing that $F^n$ is a lift of $f^{n}$ when $n$ is a non-positive integer.  Any offer of help would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $F^n$ when $n$ is nonpositive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you know that $F^n$ is a lift of $f^n$ for all $n > 0$, what remains is

1. $n = 0$, but $F^0 = \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{R}}$ and $f^0 = \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{R/Z}}$, so $\pi \circ F^0 = \pi = f^0 \circ \pi$ is trivially true, and
2. $n < 0$, where the general case will follow from the case $n = -1$ by induction like for positive $n$.

So let's look at $n = -1$.

$$\begin{align}
\pi \circ F^{-1} &= (f^{-1}\circ f) \circ \pi \circ F^{-1}\\
&= f^{-1} \circ (f \circ \pi) \circ F^{-1}\\
&= f^{-1} \circ (\pi \circ F)\circ F^{-1}\\
&= f^{-1} \circ \pi \circ (F \circ F^{-1})\\
&= f^{-1} \circ \pi.
\end{align}$$

Like multiplying with $1$ or adding $0$, composing with an identity is a useful technique for proofs.